# Getting the difference between two Lists based on certain fields

Tags: c#, linq, join, left-join, list-comparison

I'm fairly new to LINQ and I may have painted myself to a corner here. I have two lists (left and right) and I need to:

*a*) Get matching items based on certain fields

*b*) Get items on the left with no match on the right

*c*) Get items on the right with no match on the left

A match is found if certain fields are equal. Other fields may or may not contain values but must not influence the match comparison.

To get item *a* I performed a `JOIN` on both lists:

```
var q = from a in r1
        from b in r2
        where a.Prop1 == b.Prop1 && a.Prop3 == b.Prop3
        select new { a.Prop1, a.Prop2, b.Prop3 };
```

I'm not sure on where to go from here. I *think* I cannot use `.Except()` because the other properties for both lists will be different and may cause the comparison to break.

I also tried using `Left Join` and get the items with no matches:

```
 var q =
     from c in r1
     join p in r2 on c.Prop1 equals p.Prop1
     into cp
     from p in cp.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new { Prop1 = c.Prop1, Prop2 = p == null ? "N/A" : p.Prop2 };
```

however I found out that you can't compare more than one field to compare.

Can you have more than one fields on a `Left Join` with LINQ?
Are there other ways (besides LINQ) to get the difference between two lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses `Intersect` and `Except` (similar to Cuong Le's solution):

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<YourClass>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<YourClass> Members

    public bool Equals(YourClass x, YourClass y)
    {
        return
            x.Prop1.Equals(y.Prop1) && x.Prop3.Equals(y.Prop3);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(YourClass obj)
    {
        int hCode = obj.Prop1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Prop3.GetHashCode();
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}

// matched elements from both lists
var r1 = l1.Intersect<YourClass>(l2, new MyComparer());
// elements from l1 not in l2
var r2 = l1.Except<YourClass>(l2, new MyComparer());
// elements from l2 not in l1
var r3 = l2.Except<YourClass>(l1, new MyComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `Except` method use [EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx), that's why you cannot use if you have objects with different property values

But you can use another overload method [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) to customize  `EqualityComparer<T>`, assume it ignores `Pro3`

```
public class CustomComparer : EqualityComparer<A>
{
    public override int GetHashCode(A a)
    {
        int hCode = a.Pro1.GetHashCode() ^ a.Pro2.GetHashCode();
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(A a1, A a2)
    {
        return a1.Pro1.Equals(a2.Pro1) && a1.Pro2.Equals(a2.Pro2)
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Except`:

```
listA.Except(listB, new CustomComparer());
```

Comment: Thank you, although on your code `listA.Except(listA...` I think you meant `listB` on the 2nd `listA`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

a)

```
r1.Where(x=>r2.Any(y=>x.Prop1==y.Prop1&&x.Prop3==y.Prop3))
    .Select(x=>new { x.Prop1,x.Prop2,x.Prop3});
```

b)

```
r1.Where(x=>!r2.Any(y=>x.Prop1==y.Prop1&&x.Prop3==y.Prop3))
    .Select(x=>new { x.Prop1,x.Prop2,x.Prop3});
```

c)

```
r2.Where(x=>!r1.Any(y=>x.Prop1==y.Prop1&&x.Prop3==y.Prop3))
    .Select(x=>new { x.Prop1,x.Prop2,x.Prop3});
```